# Correct structure of weights for 2 output perceptron with binary input data

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to implement the perceptron algorithm with two output nodes but I'm facing three problems.

The first is, I'm not sure how to evaluate what I've done, how to create test cases?

The second, and more pressing question is, should I create an array of weights for each input pattern, that is- if my input data looks like this:

```
 0 0 0 0 0  0 0
 0 0 0 0 1  0 0
 0 0 0 1 0  0 0
 0 0 0 1 1  0 0
 0 0 1 0 0  0 0
 0 0 1 0 1  0 0
 0 0 1 1 0  0 0
 0 0 1 1 1  1 0
 0 1 0 0 0  0 0
 0 1 0 0 1  0 1
 0 1 0 1 0  0 0
 0 1 0 1 1  1 1
 0 1 1 0 0  0 0
 0 1 1 0 1  1 1
 0 1 1 1 0  1 0
 0 1 1 1 1  1 1
 1 0 0 0 0  0 0
 1 0 0 0 1  0 0
 1 0 0 1 0  0 0
 1 0 0 1 1  1 0
 1 0 1 0 0  0 0
 1 0 1 0 1  1 0
 1 0 1 1 0  1 0
 1 0 1 1 1  1 0
 1 1 0 0 0  0 0
 1 1 0 0 1  1 1
 1 1 0 1 0  1 0
 1 1 0 1 1  1 1
 1 1 1 0 0  1 0
 1 1 1 0 1  1 1
 1 1 1 1 0  1 0
 1 1 1 1 1  1 1
```

should I create for instance, one set of weights that deals with the pattern:

```
 1 1 1 1 1
```

and one set of weights that deals with the pattern:

```
 1 1 1 1 0
```

another one for:

```
 1 1 1 0 1
```

and so on.

**or**

Should I create one array of weights for each output neuron, in the above example there are two. That's what my current implementation has, but I have an inkling that what I've first described is more accurate- but I can't exactly justify why that is the case- maybe someone could explain this to me.

The third problem, likely closely related to the first two is that the algorithm converges far too quickly.

Here are the result of two executions:

output 1

```
Iteration 1 : RMSE = 0.30618621784789724
Iteration 2 : RMSE = 0.0
```

output 2

```
Iteration 1 : RMSE = 0.1767766952966369
Iteration 2 : RMSE = 0.0
```

The full implementation looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main 
{   
    static int MAX_ITER = 100;
    static double LEARNING_RATE = 0.1;
    static int theta = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    { 

        ArrayList<Group> input_group_one = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Group> input_group_two = new ArrayList<>();


        /**************
         * READ INPUT *
         **************/
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../PA-A-train.dat"));

        //do I even need this?
        int number_of_inputs = 0; 

        String line;//new variable
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) //read the line and compare
        {
            /*********************************************************************
             * GET THE LINE, SPLIT ON THE TAB FOR LABEL VS. INPUT IDENTIFICATION *
             *********************************************************************/
            String[] label_detector = line.split("\t"); //split

            /*****************************
             * GET THE INDIVIDUAL INPUTS *
             *****************************/
            String inputs = label_detector[label_detector.length - 2];
            String[] splited_inputs = inputs.split("\\s+");
            List<String> input_list = Arrays.asList(splited_inputs);

            splited_inputs = Arrays.stream(splited_inputs) //Remove null values
                    .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                    .toArray(String[]::new); 

            //for this training datum, how many features does it have
            number_of_inputs = splited_inputs.length;   //5     

            /************************************
             * GET THE LABEL (2nd LAYER OUTPUT) *
             ************************************/
            String trueLabel = label_detector[label_detector.length - 1];
            //System.out.println("this is the corresponding label: " + trueLabel);
            String[] splited_labels = trueLabel.split("\\s+");

            int number_of_output_neurons = splited_labels.length;           




            input_group_one.add(new Group( splited_inputs, splited_labels[0] ));

            input_group_two.add(new Group( splited_inputs, splited_labels[0] )); 


        }
        reader.close();

//      for (Group p : input_group_one)
//          System.out.println( "check it out: " + p.toString() );
//      ArrayList<String> weights_one = new ArrayList<>();



        //PLUS ONE FOR BIAS
        double[] weights_one = new double[ number_of_inputs + 1 ];
        double[] weights_two = new double[ number_of_inputs + 1 ];

        double localError, globalError;
        int i, p, iteration, output;

        //MAKE SURE YOU HAVE ONE FOR BIAS
        for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
        {
            weights_one[j] = randDub(-0.5, 0.5);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < weights_two.length ; j++) 
        {
            weights_two[j] = randDub(-0.5, 0.5);
        }


//      for (int j = 0; j < weights_one.length ; j++) 
//      {
//          System.out.println("weights_one[" + j + "]: " + weights_one[j]);
//          
//          System.out.println("weights_two[" + j + "]: " + weights_two[j]);
//      }



        iteration = 0;
        do 
        {
            iteration++;
            globalError = 0;

            //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
            for (p = 0; p < input_group_one.size(); p++) // !!!!! is input_group_one.size() right?
            {
                // calculate predicted class
                output = calculateOutput(theta, weights_one, input_group_one);

                // difference between predicted and actual class values
                // DO THIS INTEGER THING UP FRONT!
                localError = Integer.parseInt( input_group_one.get(iteration).value[0] ) - output;

                //update weights and bias
                for (int weight_index = 0; weight_index < input_group_one.get(iteration).value.length ; weight_index++) 
                {
                    weights_one[weight_index] +=  LEARNING_RATE * localError * Integer.parseInt( input_group_one.get(iteration).value[weight_index] );
                }
                //BIAS, (-1 because it starts from zero)
                weights_one[weights_one.length - 1] +=  LEARNING_RATE * localError;


                //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
                globalError += (localError*localError);
            }

            /* Root Mean Squared Error */
            System.out.println("Iteration "+iteration+" : RMSE = "+Math.sqrt(globalError/input_group_one.size()));
        } 
        while (globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);







    }



    public static double randDub(double min, double max) throws InterruptedException 
    {

        Random rand = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );

        double randomValue = min + (max - min) * rand.nextDouble();

        //DELAY FOR SEED CHANGE
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        return randomValue;
    }



    static int calculateOutput(int theta, double weights[], ArrayList<Group> input_group)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (Group pattern : input_group)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pattern.value.length; i++) 
            {
                //ORIGINALLY STORED AS STRING MUST CHANGE TO INT
                sum += Integer.parseInt( pattern.value[i] ) * weights[i];
            }
            //BIAS
            sum += weights[ pattern.value.length ]; 
        }
        return (sum >= theta) ? 1 : 0;

    }




}
```

This is a class I made to store the input data.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Group {

   public String key;
   public String[] value;

   public String getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   public String[] getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   Group(String[] splited_inputs, String k) 
   {
      this.key = k;
      this.value = splited_inputs;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() 
   {
       return this.key + " " + Arrays.toString(this.value);
   }
//   public String toString() 
//   {
//      String result = this.key + "::";
//
//      for (int i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) 
//      {
//          result += " " + this.value[i];
//      }
//
//      return result;
//  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only **one** set of weights for each output neuron. Otherwise how would you compute the final classification given new point? Which weights would you use? The whole point of learning parametric models is to constraint model complexity (here - number of parameters, weights) and feed it with many training samples so (statistically) the best ones for the whole group can be learned.

The network can converge rapidly (although it does not mean that it should) as the problem is trivial. You can actually look at the data and tell the exact weights "by hand". For first neuron this is [1 1 1 1 1] and bias -2.5 (or any other between -2 and -3) and for the second one it is [0 1 0 0 1] and bias -1.5 (or anything between -1 and -2).